# Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)

Tags: iphone, audio, alert

Is it possible to play some default sounds, such as when an incoming SMS/push is received?

If iOS SDK does not bundle these sound files, where can I download the same sounds?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but they use [undocumented enum values](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices), that means you should not use it on AppStore apps.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
```

iOS SDK does not bundle these sound files, but you can find them on the device in the `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/` folder. However, I believe these files are copyrighted.

Why not create a sound yourself?

Comment: I would like to play the exact similar sound, so looking for the easiest way. I have seen a lot of messaging app playing the sound too, and wonder how they do it eg. whatsapp.

Comment: Just a quick note: On iOS 5, I found that using 1007 gave me the standard Tri-Tone notification sound (same as my push notify sound)

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. If you're using the sound for debugging purposes, it's easier to just use a simple system beep if one's available, instead of creating your own.

Comment: So there is no way to use a default notification sound without using an undocumented value?  If I want to play the user default push notification sound, within my app, is this at all possible?