# How to get and play iPhone Default sound files?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)

Hi,

How to get and play iPhone default Sound files in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it's undocumented. You wouldn't be able to do this in an App Store app. See here: [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)