# has Iphone built in beep sound effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, beep

hi i need to use beep on iphone, but the only thing i have found is this

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"wav"];

    SystemSoundID soundID;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);

    [soundPath release];
```

it is working and good code but i need to import the alert.wav file.But i rather do this with native (built in) sounds if there exist.

thanks for all the answers
cs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reading the documentation of Apple and [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices), I'm almost certain that you can play that wanted sound without carrying it.

You can do this:

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1005);`

that should do.

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)

Comment: Reading the documentation on that function, it seems that using such pre-defined IDs no longer works on new OS versions and, if it does, that doing so is a violation of App Store guidelines and might get one's app rejected.

Comment: Does anybody have info on whether using 'AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1005);` will get the app rejected for sure? because I google'd it and everybody says "might/may get rejected". I am in the same situation as above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.