# iphone Play different alert sounds for correct or wrong multiple choice quiz answer

Tags: iphone, xcode, alert

I want to play a different alert sound if the multiple choice option answer is correct or  wrong. I have code for the correct and wrong answer as follows

```
if (questionNumber == 1) {
        [self correctAnswer];
    }

if (questionNumber == 2) {
        [self wrongAnswer];
    }
```

I have created the correct IBAction Alert code. can I create a simple play.alert statement under either the correct or wrong answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use default Apple sounds, use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone), and click on the link he has there to try out different sounds.

If you would like to play custom sounds, the easiest way is with `AVAudioPlayer`:

First of all, you will need to add the `AVFoundation` framework to your project.  It is very easy from there:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES];
AVAudioPlayer *sound = audioPlayers[url];
NSError *error = nil;
sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[sound play];
```

Comment: Hi Wolflink, thanks but i'm not sure how to implement your code. I will use AVFoundation. Do I apply an IBAction to the button in the .h? Is it a @property to synthesise? is it a -(void) or BOOL. I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. sorry!  this is the youtube tutorial and its code links that I based my app on. The 4 multiple choice buttons are what i want to make correct/wrong sounds http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uw2pXE9JFDU code:http://developersmp.webs.com/apps/documents/ (choose how to make a more advanced quiz). Would be really grateful for more help.

Comment: Have a correct answer function and incorrect answer function, each with code like the code I have above.  Replace "path" in the code with @"your_filename_here_including_extension" (srry I didn't make that clear, I must have just copied and pasted without thinking).  Call those functions when you want to play the sound (yes, probably at some level from IBAction functions from your buttons).