# How to play user device notification sound in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on app and there I need to play sound when there is FCM notification. 
I know I can play custom sound and I can play system sound(iOS). see below for code to play system sound

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone) link and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525942/play-audio-ios-objective-c/18958454#18958454) link but nothing is what I want.

**What I want:**

> I want that When the fcm notification come, I want to play the message/Notification sound that has been selected by user as default notification/message sounds. Also if the device is on silent it should not ring in this condition

NOTE: I know we can send sound name in FCM payload and add similar sound file in bundle But I really want to play sound that has been selected by user.

Please help me. I am right now helpless to play that sound.