# How to play default notification sound of iOS in my app

Tags: ios, swift

i want to play default notification sound of device in my app.

currenlty i am using following code but this is not actual notification sound.

```
        let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1315
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
```

if possible to play sound without SystemSoundID. it will be good.
becuse SystemSoundID play specific sound.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5250337/3485420
read this.. i hope it will help you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play alert sound (same as default message ringtone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250200/play-alert-sound-same-as-default-message-ringtone)